# Hacer que mi server responda

Tags: php, servidor, puertos

estoy "escuchando" un puerto de mi servidor, tengo un dispositivo GPS que me manda un código, y necesito darle una respuesta ¿cómo puedo responderle?.

Soy nuevo en este tema. ¿Cómo puedo capturar eso con PHP?

Comment: Acá tenes un ejemplo de como capturar y responderle: http://php.net/manual/es/sockets.examples.php

Comment: Ah, es con sockets. Muchas gracias :)